# GBM model : why is the validation accuracy fluctuating on grid search in h2o R

Tags: r, h2o

I'm using the package H2O in R and i'm trying to improve my score with gbm model. I tried a grid search using a training and a valid sets. 
But when it finished, the log loss curves between the two sets is very different. Indeed there's overfitting on my train set so the accuracy is higher than my valid set

```
Here on H2O, my gbm's parameters :
ntrees = 100, 
max_depth = 3, 
learn_rate = 0.01, 
nfolds = 5,
seed = 1234
```

Could you give me some way to resolve my problems ?

Answer (score 0):

For help on tuning a H2O GBM in R I would recommend reviewing this tuning guide: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/tutorials/gbm/gbmTuning.Rmd.

There are a lot of reasons you could be seeing overfitting from the predictors you use, the features you engineer, the way you split up your data, and finally the way you tune your model.

Without seeing your specific dataset and the specific code you ran, it would be hard do give you an exact reason for why you are having issues with overfitting.